# Spring security navigation to other pages after user is logged in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

First, if this is a duplicate please someone point on that. But currently, I can't find that anyone asked this question. I have this spring security configuration:

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/admin/adminDashboard.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And i.e. this controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class AdministrationController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/banAppealsList.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String banAppealsList() {
        return "banAppealsList";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/adminDashboard.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminDashboard() {
        return "adminDashboard";

    }
}
```

As you can see it intercepts `/admin/**` URL. After logging, it redirects me to `adminDashboard.jsp` page. But problem I'm facing is: How to redirect from my `adminDashboard.jsp` page to other secured pages without being asked for credentials? Basically, if I want to go on `banAppealsList.htm` it asks me for credentials again.

**EDIT:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Define a filter to enable Spring Security, be sure to use the suggested 
        name 'springSecurityFilterChain' -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>banAppeal.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
            <!-- Obviously, problem was here -->
        <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I am working on an simple example at the moment that uses similar configuration and when I return "redirect:<name>" it does not ask me for credentials after logging in, as those are stored in the session. Do you return "redirect:/admin/banAppealsList.htm" in adminDashboard()?

Comment: @RafalBorowiec Just tried that. Still not working. I made a redirect method which redirects to banAppealsList.htm and added hyperlink in adminDashboard page.

Comment: It looks weird might be your user is logged out on redirect? For example User admin is logged out, session expired.

Comment: @RomanC And how to make it to remain logged in? Sorry, I'm new in Spring MVC and Spring security.

Comment: @brano you could add your web.xml configuration into the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status of you being logged in should be stored in a session. Since this doesn't happen for you, I suspect you haven't configured your SpringSecurityFilterChain correctly, as that is the component storing it in a session.

You should have about this in your web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Edit: in hindsight, the problem wasn't actually related to Spring Security, but to the fact you had set the session cookies to secure, which means they won't work with non-secure urls -> new session every time http urls are used. But glad the answer got you pushed in the right direction on checking the problem from web.xml.

Comment: I actually think I found problem right there (in web.xml). My cookie-confige secure property was set to true. I removed that property and now it works fine.

Comment: @brano that property tells browser to only use the cookies on secure (https-enabled) requests. If you don't have those that explains the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you should use some kind of session, witch stores your credentials and server checks them, when pages are requested from same session. I haven't used this framework but I have used the play framework, witch doesn't have session readily, but it can handle cookies, witch can be used to create these sessions.